# iBooks able to read Files in Other App's SandBox

Tags: iphone, ipad, sandbox, ibooks

I want to know if i can develop an app that would download books in epub format from a website and then it would be accessed by iBooks ( iPad app for Reading books ) to read that file.
The issue in my view is that an application can access files present in its own SandBox and it is not allowed to access any file outside it. Please explain if there is any way that files can be downloaded to a specific location on iPad which would be accessible by other apps.

Thanks!
Taimur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, apps generally cannot access files outside their sandbox (except Apple's own apps, of course, but it is very unlikely they would interfere in another app's sandbox).

However, that is why Apple introduced `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone i have found the answer!
http://andycodes.tumblr.com/tagged/uidocumentinteractioncontroller

Comment: Accept oles answer instead of creating a new answer.